# JupyterLab - python open() function results in FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, directory-structure, jupyter-lab

I am trying to open an existing file in a subfolder of the current working directory. This is my command:

`fyle = open('/SPAdes/default/{}'.format(file), 'r')`

The `file`variable contains the correct filename, the folder structure is correct (working on macOS), and the file exists.

This command, however, results if this error message:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: [filename]`

Does it have anything to do with the way JupyterLab works? How am I supposed to specify the folder srtucture on Jupyter? I am able to create a new file in the current folder, but I am not able to create one in a subfolder of the current one (results in the same error message).

The folder structure is recognized on the same Jupyter notebook by bash commands, but I am somehow not able to access subfolders using python code.
Any idea as to what is wrong with the way I specified the folder structure?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `No such file or directory` is likely due to your file path not being correct. Have you tried to print the results of `'/SPAdes/default/{}'.format(file)`? Try a fully qualified file path including drive letter to see if that works.

Comment: try `os.getcwd()` to confirm that you're reading from the correct path.

Comment: @RikkiH I confirmed that the directory was the correct one.

Comment: @Mike-SMT the relative path was correct, but adding the absolute path solved the problem. Not sure why python on Jupyter cannot work with relative paths though. Is there something peculiar to the way Jupyter interprets directory paths?

Comment: I cannot say for sure with Jupyter. Never worked with it. But something seams off with your relative path. If the path was correct it should work. Is that relative path in the same directory as your main python file?

Comment: In `/SPAdes`, the `/` means root directory, which is most likely not what you want. Maybe try with `./SPAdes` where the `.` means current directory where your Jupyter notebook file is.

Comment: Jupyter is fine with relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn’t be a forward slash in front of `SPAdes`.

Paths starting with a slash exist high up in file hierarchy. You said this is a sub-directory of your current working directory.

Comment: Specifically, `/` means the system root directory.